# route group prefixed for admin

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How do you have a the start of the route to have admin at the begining of the route like '/admin/attributes/1/edit in the routes group collection instead of just /attributes/1/edit

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'Admin'), function() {
    Route::resource('attributes', 'AttributesController');
    Route::resource('brands', 'BrandsController');
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductsController');
    Route::resource('tags', 'TagsController');
    Route::resource('roles', 'RolesController');
    Route::resource('suppliers', 'SuppliersController');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a `prefix`

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function() 
{
    // routes here
});
```

See [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-prefixing)

Comment: I did that but I get this error in my blade page for the route links. Route [attributes.index] not defined. (View: C:\Users\kirkie99\Documents\websites\shoppingsite\shoppingsite\app\views\attributes\index.blade.php)

Comment: Can you show the list of your routes using `artisan route` command. Your route names might be prefixed with `admin` as in `admin.attributes.index`

Comment: check `php artisan route:list` to chechk your route names